# Git Workflow short-lived feature branch with squash

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, squash, trunk

I have a questions concerned about the following git workflow:

```
 - checkout master
 - pull -r origin master
 - checkout new_feature
 - rebase master
 - checkout master
 - merge --squash new_feature
 - commit -m "F"
 - push origin master
```

Now you will end up with the following setup, assuming some commits **C,D,E** happened on the **new_feature** branch:

```
Master             A --B --------------- F
                    \ 
new_feature          \ -- C -- D -- E
```

Local Master and Origin Master pointing to **F**. The F commit involves **C,D,E**.

Now I want to delete the **new_feature** Branch by running:

```
branch -d new_feature
```

*error: The branch 'new_feature' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D new_feature'.*

Why do I get the error here and why does git not know, that the branch has been fully merged, just with the squash command?

(even a git diff does not show any differences)

Comment: Your graph does not match your commands. After rebasing onto master, you will end up with `a-b-f-c-d-e`.

Comment: @knittl the graph is correct, a merge with squash happened. As I pointed out, the commits C,D,E are squashed together to F

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the final merge. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with these commands the *new_feature* branch is not **formally** merged, in the sense that it is not a parent node of the merged commit. What git will not check is that your changes have actually been merged. You know, but for git it is not trivial to know.

I have tried your workflow, then I have re-merged again the squashed-merged branch and then it can be deleted.

It is actually not an error, it is a check to prevent that you lose your work.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the answer. This workflow seems to be recommended for short-lived feature branches in trunk based dev. Do you see any issues arrive with the check? I would end up just deleteing the branch anyways, since I do not want to have a full merge into master.

Comment: Actually, I had never used `merge --squash` until I read your question and have tried it out of curiosity. I understand it is a recommended workflow for trunk-based dev if it is meaningful to squash all commits together. Personally, I like to customize my squashes, move commits up&down, before merging/rebasing.